# Staircase is not working, there are bugs in my code

Tags: java

I did the stair case problem in java.  I wrote it but it did not work.  So I am posting it so that if anybody could check for my mistake.  Thanks.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int f=n;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;i<f;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for(int k=0;k<=i;k++)
            {
                System.out.print("#");
            }
            f=f-1;
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
```

The input was `6`

and the output pattern should be

```
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```

but mine is not producing anything 
the code is fixed the code should have been

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int f=n;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<f;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for(int k=0;k<=i;k++)
            {
                System.out.print("#");
            }
            f=f-1;
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
```

thanks for all the help guys ...blessed to have a community like this..:)

Comment: Is there no output or is your output a lot of spaces?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong

```
            for(int j=0;i<f;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
```

Should be

```
       for(int j=0;j<f;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
```

You switched i and j so your never exiting that for loop

Comment: Your code did not pass this test case.
Input (stdin)
6
Your Output (stdout)
      #
     ##
    ###
   ####
  #####
 ######
Expected Output
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
Compiler Message
Wrong Answer

Comment: can you find a better format? its hard to tell the difference .  An issue could be that your adding an extra space with      System.out.println(" "); at the end.  Maybe change that to System.out.println("")

Comment: let me know if that last bit helps

Answer (score 2):

Let's break down what each part of your code is doing, and see if the answer becomes obvious:

```
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    int f=n;
```

So, we read in a number (in this case 6) and set both `n` and `f` to be this value.

```
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
```

Here, we're going to repeat the following block 6 times, with `i` equal to 0, then 1, then 2, 3, 4, and 5. We'll stop when `i` is no longer less than `n`, which is 6 in this case.

So, we start the loop, and `i` is 0. `n` and `f` are both still 6 because we haven't changed them.

```
        for(int j=0;i<f;j++)
        {
```

Another loop, this time we're starting with `j` at 0, and continuing until `i` is no longer less than `f`. What were `i` and `f` again? `i` is 0 (we're on the first time through that outer loop) and `f` is still 6. 0 is less than 6, so we start this loop.

```
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
```

We print a space, and find the end of the loop, so we go back around to the `for(int j=0...` loop, incrementing `j` (because we said `j++` in the start of this loop).

So, now the values we have are: `j = 1`, `i = 0` and `f = 6`. We check the loop condition - `i<f` - and 0 is still less than 6, so we repeat the loop again, and print another space, and again repeat the above.

Nothing within that loop is ever changing the values of `i` or `f`, so the condition for the loop (`i<f`) is always true, and we just end up in an infinite loop, printing spaces forever. `j` increments on each iteration, so it goes up to 1, 2, 3, etc, but as you never refer to it again, that's irrelevant.

So, the problem is that you need to change the loop condition, so that you can exit the loop, and move on to the other parts of your program.

Given that your loop is iterating over `j`, and you're incrementing that as you go, my guess is that you want to be using that to determine whether or not to end the loop - so, you probably want to make it the condition `j<f` instead of `i<f`, that is:

```
        for(int j=0;j<f;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
```

I'm not sure if that will make your program perfect, or if you'll hit another similar problem, but hopefully by breaking it down like this you can see the sort of thought process you need to go through in order to solve whatever the next problem you encounter is. Basically, you need to pretend to be the computer and work through each line individually, writing down what the value of each variable is every time it changes. It's not hard, but it is time-consuming and annoying - welcome to programming!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is plain easy and could be done with couple of lines. All you need is just two counters (one for rows, and another to split `empty` part and `#` part).

```
int rows = 6;
for (int i = rows; i > 0; i--) {
    for (int j = rows; j > 0; j--)
        System.out.print((rows - j + 1) < i ? ' ' : '#');
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Answers are better if you can post some explanation to help someone learn from what you've suggested, rather than just the working code. Also, the OP has clearly said that he's learning the language, so reducing the code to complex, single-line statements is unlikely to help them learn. It also sets a terrible example if they have any plans to become a professional software developer - if I encountered something like this in real code, I'd re-write it immediately to make its intent clear, rather than being 'clever' but totally obscure.

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave I have added comments to the post

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 streams, `String.format` you could solve the problem in a more succinct manner:

```
int limit = 6;
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, limit)
    .forEach(i -> System.out.printf("%" + limit + "s%n", String.join("", Collections.nCopies(i, "#"))));
```

This is how the "#" gets repeated:

```
String.join("", Collections.nCopies(i, "#")
```

Using `System.out.printf` with `"%" + digit + "s"` right aligns a string.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this also for `StairCase` pattern.

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
for(int j=n;j>=0;j--){
if(j<=i)
System.out.print("#");
else
System.out.print(" ");
}
System.out.println();
}
}
```

for input 6 the output is

```
      #
     ##
    ###
   ####
  #####
 ######
```